# Highcharts doesn't expand <div> to proper height in Chrome/Safari and doesn't display at all in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, highcharts

I've been using Highcharts on a Wordpress website for about 9 months without problems. Last week I updated to Wordpress 4.4 and soon after I noticed that my charts didn't render properly anymore (may be unrelated, not sure). In Chrome or Safari the div doesn't expand height-wise at all so the charts aren't legible. In Firefox, they initially displayed the same behavior as the other two browsers, but now just an empty div displays. I tried changing the order I list my scripts in my header.php file, but that didn't seem to have any effect. I also removed all other scripts except the highcharts script, but that didn't work either.

I've also tried adjusting code in my function.php file using this method on CSS Tricks: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/
but no luck there either.

Here's an example of a chart that's not rendering correctly:
http://siliconvalleyindicators.org/data/people/talent-flows-diversity/total-science-engineering-degrees-conferred/

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you setup webpage with height:100%, instad of 400px which you have at this moment? Have you tried to add float:left; for chart container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this element for holding chart:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;" data-highcharts-chart="0" id="hc1">
```

Replace heigh with some value with px, em etc.

```
style="width:100%; height:200px;"
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny. Unfortunately, when I set a specific height with px, em, etc. the div holding the chart overflows the space and covers over the tabs below it (The ones labeled Sources, Definitions, Notes, Data). If I set overflow:hidden in my CSS it fixes this, but then you can't see the whole chart. When I apply this suggestion in Firefox, I just get a blank white box. The maddening thing about all this is it was working fine with the height set to 100% (in all browsers) prior to last week.

Comment: Remove padding from that div:
#hc1 {
    padding: 0;
}

Comment: OK. I'm making progress. The charts weren't working in Firefox because I had installed an add-on called Privacy Badger.

Comment: I removed the padding from the #hc1 div and that fixed it! Now it works with height:100% OR height:400px! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
GET http://siliconvalleyindicators.org/data/people/talent-flows-diversity/total-science-engineering-degrees-conferred/js/functions.js
```

If you open your js console you will see that `js/functions.js` can't be found. Use an absolute link like this: `<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/js/functions.js`